# Show only specific fields on Edit page when a Term is selected

Tags: taxonomy-terms, entities

How do I show on (content type) Edit page only specific fields? 
For example if I have selected the Laptop term then I should see Procesor, RAM and HDD fields and if I select TV term then I should see Screen size, Brand, Screent type fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[conditional fields](http://drupal.org/project/conditional_fields)  is very powerful you can achieve your need with it. read **README.TXT** file carefully

Comment: @kingbt,Your welcome